# NextJS and Netlify don't load tailwind CSS on some pages

Tags: next.js, netlify

I develop an application in Next JS which is published on Netlify, which uses Tailwind CSS for the views.

The problem is that when I published in Netlifly, some of the pages that are in the root directory, do not load the CSS if I reload the page, but if I navigate to that page, the CSS does load.

The error cannot be replicated locally, locally it works fine, productive (Netlify) is the problem

Here the directory structure

```
category1/index.tsx
category2/index.tsx
category3/index.tsx
about.js
index.js
contact.js
```

The categories are directories because I use dynamic content through a slug, the problem is with the static pages in the root directory.

Comment: Post your `tailwind.config.js` file, that can give more info

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('tailwind-scrollbar')({ nocompatible: true }),
    require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
  ],
}